# Are there any issues with Isolated Storage and Windows Vista?

Tags: c#, .net, isolatedstorage

My problem is similar but not the same as that exhibited in:

> ["Could not find file" when using Isolated Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626/could-not-find-file-when-using-isolated-storage)

I've written an application that saves user settings in a file in isolated storage, I'm using the user store for assembly storage.

The application checks for a file in Isolated Storage on startup, and if it's not there assumes that it's the first time the application has been run and asks the user to configure it, this process then saves to Isolated Storage.

In Windows XP this works fine, I've not seen any issues whatsoever. However, I was running a demonstration to the client on their Windows Vista laptop and when I ran the client for the 2nd time to show that the settings were saved the application couldn't find the file.

Are there any known issues that might cause this to happen in Windows Vista and not Windows XP?

Both references to retrieve Isolated Storage are in the same .cs file, so it's definitely the same assembly that is making the call, and I didn't log in as another user, so I know it's the same user.

Comment: Did you log off and log back on as the same user?

Comment: No, Same user same version of the application, and same user session.

Answer (score 0):

Isolated storage location will change as soon as you change the application version.
The proper place to store application configuration is in \ProgramData for all users and \Users\\AppData for user settings.

Comment: Application version didn't change. Install, Run, Configure, Close, Run, Can't find file.

Comment: maybe your application crash silently and didn't save the file.

Comment: No file is saved before exit. way before the application is closed.